# Перечислите компиляторы C++

Tags: c++

*Перечислите некоторые компиляторы C++ общего пользования. К каким компиляторам вы имеете доступ? Для каждого компилятора укажите, предоставляет ли он интегрированную среду разработки (IDE), в которой имеются редактор, компилятор, компоновщик, отладчик и исполняющая система. Альтернативой является компилятор с командной строкой.*

Я знаю только компилятор **microsoft visual c++ (msvc)** - *micrsoft visual studio*.
Про **mingw** не знаю, но его можно внедрить в *micrsoft visual studio* при помощи open folder и CppProperties.json вроде бы.
Опять же в той же *microsoft visual studio code* компилятор **gcc** вроде бы, он же и в *sublime text 3* вроде как.

*p.s. вопрос из книги Уильяма Топпа, Уильяма Форда "Структуры данных в C++", перевод 2006 года.*

Comment: Первая ссылка https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Категория:Компиляторы_C%2B%2B

Comment: @dIm0n gcc и mingw предоставляют ide или нет? Из ссылки непонятно.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Интегрированная_среда_разработки

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C++_compilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уважаемый Tim,
я постараюсь ответить на Ваш вопрос кратко и  по делу:

Сейчас есть три компилятора и несколько сред разработки, которые популярны и покрывают собой, наверное, 95% всего "зоопарка" компиляторов и IDE по количеству "случаев использования". Оценка, конечно же, на глаз.

Компиляторы:

1. Как вы уже написали - msvc. Это компилятор. Разработан понятно кем.
2. [gcc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection). Лозунг большинства разработчиков на C++ - "gcc - наше всё!". gcc - это, вообще говоря, не только компилятор языка C++, там все немного сложнее, лучше прочитать статью
3. [clang](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang). Очеь модерновый и современный компилятор. Разработан в значительной степени Google / Apple, но развивается сообществом и имеет открытый код.

Но этим всё не ограничивается: есть много разных компиляторов, которые используются в специализированых случаях или по историческим причинам.

Среды разработки: Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, Clion, ну и разные другие, типа Code Blocks. На эту тему - лучше погуглить.

Теперь о том, как это всё соотносится.

Почти все среды разработки позволяют подключить к себе любой компилятор. Были определенные трудности с Visual Studio, но современная VS позволяет, вроде бы, подключать любой компилятор.

И напоследок. Вы читаете книгу 2006 года. И  этот вопрос - учебный, скорее, вопрос для размышления. Нет большого смысла задавать его здесь, ведь Вам, скорее, полезно самому найти ответ. Кстати, я более чем уверен, что в 2006 году список "лидеров" был бы другим, и туда входил бы Borland, например.

А mingw - это пакет (в том смысле, что "набор программ"), который позволяет gcc работать под Windows

Дерзайте!

Comment: Visual Studio Code... Это не IDE Это редактор с плагинами.

Comment: @ヒミコ А в чем, собственно, разница - главное, что функциональность реализована, а как именно - дело десятое.